# IF ELSE dentro de un array para datatables de JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Quiero poner un `if` dentro de este `array` para que en la tabla si es **estado=1** mostrar **activo** y si es igual a **0** muestre **INACTIVO**, lo e hecho así y me sale este error:

> syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

En la línea del `If`, se puede hacer de este modo o hay otra forma de hacerlo?

```
case 'listarperiodos':

        $respuesta=$objperiodo->MostrarTodos();
        //var_dump($respuesta);

        $c=0;
        $data= Array();
        foreach($respuesta as $row => $item)
        {
        $c++;

            $data[]=array(
                "0"=>"<label id='lblcod_periodo$c'>" . $item["cod_periodo"] . "</label>",
                "1"=>"<label id='lblanio$c'>" . $item["anio"] . "</label>",
                "2"=>"<label id='lbln_ciclo$c'>" . $item["n_ciclo"] . "</label>",
                "3"=>"<label id='lbldescripcion$c'>" . $item["descripcion"] . "</label>",               
                "4"=>"<label id='lblestado$c'>". if($item["estado"] <> '0'){echo "ACTIVO";}else{echo "INACTIVO";}. "</label>",
                "5"=>"<button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='agregar(" . $c . ")'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></button> "
                );
        }
        $results = array(
            "sEcho"=>1, //Información para el datatables
            "iTotalRecords"=>count($data), //enviamos el total registros al datatable
            "iTotalDisplayRecords"=>count($data), //enviamos el total registros a visualizar
            "aaData"=>$data);
        echo json_encode($results);

    break;
```

Comment: Te marca el error por el **.** (concatenado) ya que no debe de preceder por éste, podrías hacer ese `if` fuera del `array` y guardar en una variable el resultado y concatenar esa variable en el array,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te comenté puedes hacerlo de esta forma, guardando en una `variable` la `string` de la validación y esta variable concatenarla en el `array`.

```
     case 'listarperiodos':

                $respuesta=$objperiodo->MostrarTodos();
                //var_dump($respuesta);

                $c=0;
                $data= Array();
                foreach($respuesta as $row => $item)
                {
                $c++;

        if($item["estado"] <> '0'){
        //echo "ACTIVO";
        $estado = "ACTIVO";
        }else{
        //echo "INACTIVO";
        $estado = "INACTIVO";
        }

                $data[]=array(
                    "0"=>"<label id='lblcod_periodo$c'>" . $item["cod_periodo"] . "</label>",
                    "1"=>"<label id='lblanio$c'>" . $item["anio"] . "</label>",
                    "2"=>"<label id='lbln_ciclo$c'>" . $item["n_ciclo"] . "</label>",
                    "3"=>"<label id='lbldescripcion$c'>" . $item["descripcion"] . "</label>",               
                    "4"=>"<label id='lblestado$c'>".$estado."</label>",
                    "5"=>"<button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='agregar(" . $c . ")'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></button> "
                    );
            }
            $results = array(
                "sEcho"=>1, //Información para el datatables
                "iTotalRecords"=>count($data), //enviamos el total registros al datatable
                "iTotalDisplayRecords"=>count($data), //enviamos el total registros a visualizar
                "aaData"=>$data);
            echo json_encode($results);

        break;
```

Comment: Mil Gracias brother! si me sirvio!

Comment: No es nada, para eso estamos! :D

Answer (score 0):

Otra manera de hacerlo es utilizar un operador ternario, el cual puedes concatenarlo como string:

```
 $respuesta=$objperiodo->MostrarTodos();
    //var_dump($respuesta);

    $c=0;
    $data= Array();
    foreach($respuesta as $row => $item)
    {
    $c++;

        $data[]=array(
            "0"=>"<label id='lblcod_periodo$c'>" . $item["cod_periodo"] . "</label>",
            "1"=>"<label id='lblanio$c'>" . $item["anio"] . "</label>",
            "2"=>"<label id='lbln_ciclo$c'>" . $item["n_ciclo"] . "</label>",
            "3"=>"<label id='lbldescripcion$c'>" . $item["descripcion"] . "</label>",               
            "4"=>"<label id='lblestado$c'>". ( ($item["estado"] <> '0') ? "ACTIVO" : "INACTIVO" ) . "</label>",
            "5"=>"<button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='agregar(" . $c . ")'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></button> "
            );
    }
    $results = array(
        "sEcho"=>1, //Información para el datatables
        "iTotalRecords"=>count($data), //enviamos el total registros al datatable
        "iTotalDisplayRecords"=>count($data), //enviamos el total registros a visualizar
        "aaData"=>$data);
    echo json_encode($results);

break;
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, pero ya resolví el error! :D

Answer (score 0):

Prueba un IF corto de una linea dentro del Array, cambia la linea del IF(){} por esta otra.

"4"=>"". (($item["estado"]  <> '0')? 'echo "ACTIVO";' : 'echo "INACTIVO";') . "",

Donde: la expresion de comparacion esta dentro del parentesis y la condicion verdadera se coloca despues del signo de interrogacion y la contraria o else esta despues de dos puntos:

(($item["estado"]  <> '0')? 'echo "ACTIVO";' : 'echo "INACTIVO";')

Esta es una prueba del codigo que hice en PHP y funciona:

```html
<?php

$item["estado"]='1';
$c=0;

$data[]=array(        
    "4"=>"<label id='lblestado$c'>". (($item["estado"]  <> '0')? 'echo "ACTIVO";' : 'echo "INACTIVO";') . "</label>",
    );

 print_r($data);   

?>
```